# When proving things how do I defer choosing a values?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

The best example is what I've just tried to prove. Usually I do these proofs in 2 or 3 passes, or draw a margin to separate notes. In the example I want to defer picking an $\epsilon_f$ and $\epsilon_g$ for a while, rather than doing them in a margin and giving them values (rather than mentioning them) later.

I wish to do the proof in "one pass", like below. (see the notes in bold for what I am not happy writing)

I wish to prove that given:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)) = L, L\ne0$
and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(g(x))=0$ but $\exists\delta>0:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies0<|g(x)|$ (basically, $g(x)$ isn't zero  about $a$ for some range about $a$)

Then:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\infty\iff\forall A>0\exists \delta>0:0<|x-a|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|>A$$

### Proof

Let $A>0$ be given.

Let $\epsilon_f>0$ be given  **<---I don't mean this, I mean "consider an $\epsilon_f>0$ maybe?**
then $\exists\delta_f>0:0<|x-a|<\delta_f\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon_f\implies|L|-\epsilon_f<|f(x)|$

(where might I write a note about what form I am going for, like "want to show $A<\frac{|L|-\epsilon_f}{|g(x)|}<|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|$", **This invalidates "let $\epsilon_f>0$ be given" as not just any $\epsilon_f$ works, also this may not be true for $\delta_f$, we need to look at what g does before I can write this**

We know $\exists\delta_{g_1}>0:0<|x-a|<\delta_{g_1}\implies0<|g(x)|$

Let $\frac{1}{\epsilon_g}>0$ be given **again, I don't mean this, you can't just give me one**
then $\exists\delta_{g_2}>0:0<|x-a|<\delta_{g_2}\implies|g(x)|<\frac{1}{\epsilon_g}$

using $\delta_g=\min(\delta_{g_1},\delta_{g_2})$ we see that if $0<|x-a|<\delta_g\implies0<|g(x)|<\frac{1}{\epsilon_g}\implies\frac{1}{|g(x)|}>\epsilon_g$

Letting $\delta=\min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$ we see that for $0<|x-a|<\delta$ that:

$$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|>\frac{|L|-\epsilon_f}{|g(x)|}>(|L|-\epsilon_f)\epsilon_g$$

Now if we let $\epsilon_f=\frac{|L|}{2}$ and $\epsilon_g=\frac{2A}{|L|}$ we see

$$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|>\frac{|L|}{2}.\frac{2A}{|L|}=A$$

QED.

I don't like doing most of the proof to then go write something like

"then $\exists\delta_{g_2}>0:0<|x-a|<\delta_{g_2}\implies|g(x)|<\frac{|L|}{2A}$"

But I cannot write "let $\frac{1}{\epsilon_g}>0$ be given" because you can't just give me one! What should I be writing.

Comment: One thing I've seen and done a lot, is to first go through the proof assuming that such an $\epsilon$ existed, and then when you've gotten to the end to actually figure out what it was, reword the entire proof to use that value from the beginning.

Comment: @Hayden that's what I mean. 2 passes. I hate that. What I've written above avoids it but I'm not sure saying "consider $\epsilon_f>0$" means what I want it to mean.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant now.  Agreed, as you're trying to show the existence of such an $\epsilon_f>0$.  Logically I think that what you did above works; you assumed that such an $\epsilon_f$ does exist, and showed that it was finite and greater than zero; if the claim were wrong, it would have produced a contradiction.  Maybe just adding "We shall assume such a $\epsilon_f>0$ exists, and use this to find the necessary value it would take," and then at the end writing "Now given any $A$, we take $\epsilon_f=\text{blah}$, which we know from the above fulfills the necessary conditions."

Comment: You can use \left( and \right) to get the brackets/modulus signs the right size (you always need both for it to work, they come in pairs). E.g.: $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ and $\displaystyle \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ (right-click to see code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of your $\epsilon_f$ is to make sure $|f(x)|$ is bounded below for all $x$ near $a$. So it doesn't matter what this is, as long as it's positive. Then write something like: "Let $\epsilon_f>0$ be arbitrary" or "Fix $\epsilon_f:=x$". Here $x$ can be any real number such that $x<|L|$, since we want $|L|-\epsilon_f>0$. Apart from that, it doesn't matter, you just want to bound $|f|$ from below. After you have fixed $\epsilon_f$, you choose your $\delta_f$ accordingly.

The next thing you want to show is:

$$A<\frac{|L|-\epsilon_f}{|g(x)|}$$

which is equivalent to:
$$A|g(x)|<|L|-\epsilon_f$$

So now you *choose* $\epsilon_g$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|y|<\epsilon_g$ you have: $A|y|<|L|-\epsilon_f$. A possible choice for $\epsilon_g$ is $\frac{|L|-\epsilon_f}{A}$. Something smaller also works. After you have chosen $\epsilon_g$, you can choose $\delta_g$ such that:
$$|x-a|<\delta_g \implies |g(x)|<\epsilon_g$$

If you now put $\delta:=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$, you get the desired inequality.

**Edit:** I'll write the proof in full, so you can compare it.

Let $A>0$ be given. Fix $\epsilon_f>0$ such that $|L|-\epsilon_f>0$. By hypothesis, there exists a $\delta_f$ such that: $|x-a|<\delta_f\implies |L|-\epsilon_f<|f(x)|$. Now define $\epsilon_g:=\frac{|L|-\epsilon_f}{A}$. Because $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, there is a $\delta_g$ such that: $|x-a|<\delta_g\implies |g(x)|<\epsilon_g$. Put $\delta:=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$. Then we have:
$$|x-a|<\delta\implies A|g(x)|<A\epsilon_g=|L|-\epsilon_f<|f(x)|$$

This is equivalent to: $$|x-a|<\delta\implies A<\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$$

Comment: So I'd write "Let $\epsilon_f>0$ be arbitrary" then later on write "fixing $\epsilon_f = 5$" say? This sounds perfect!

Comment: @AlecTeal No you have to fix it beforehand, since your $\epsilon_g$ will depend on $\epsilon_f$.

Comment: So I'd say "fixing $\epsilon_g$ and $\epsilon_f$ as..." then? My lines that read "let $\epsilon_f>0$" should read "let $\epsilon_f>0$ be arbitrary, and I fix them later on? By the way thanks for taking the time to answer, but I get the proof (I wrote it!) I just don't want to say "there exists a delta such that ... < $\frac{2A}{|L|}$" - I want to do it in one pass.

Comment: @AlecTeal Something like "Let $\epsilon_f>0$ arbitrary but fixed". You want to fix it now, since in the next step you fix $\epsilon_g$

Comment: So where I have left my notes in bold, what would you write (that was the crux of the question) "Let whatever$>0$ and fixed"?

Comment: @AlecTeal I expanded my answer